# Secure/protected content distribution for Android app

Tags: android, cdn, protected

Here is my scenario: I need to distribute optional content packages for an Android application in a secure/protected way, i.e. prevent download of the content from outside the application. The content consists of zipped SQLite database creation files with sizes up to 4 Megabytes. The packages will be updated 4 times a year. I have currently about 1000 active installations. This means at peak times traffic for downloading the content package updates could yield in about 4 GB per day. The installation base of the app grows  by roughly 100 users per day.

Based on the scenario I wonder how to solve the following issues:

1. What would be the best way to distribute the content? HTTPS transport? What would be a recommended way to do authentication (e.g. passwords, certificates)? Should I use password protected Zip files instead?
2. Which infrastructure should be used for content delivery that fits the following criteria:

   - support of the protection mechanism from 1) out of the box
   - easy to setup and maintain
   - scalable and download nodes in Europe and the US
   - relatively inexpensive (not more than 30$ per month). Ideally pay-as-you-go bandwidth.

I was considering CDNs like SoftLayer, Amazon CloudFront, etc. Any recommendations?

Comment: "I need to distribute optional content packages for an Android application in a secure/protected way, i.e. prevent download of the content from outside the application." -- by definition, that is impossible. Whatever means you use can be reverse-engineered from the app and used elsewhere. You can use code obfuscation and such to try to make this a bit more difficult, but that's pretty much it.

Comment: I am aware that it's impossible to get a 100% secure solution. Still I don't want that just anybody grabs the data by simply surfing to the download URL. So I would be great to use at least password protection and hide the password in the application to make things harder. Any recommendations how I could do that?

Comment: 100 users per day and you have 1000 users? I don't think you can derive meaningful statistics from that.

Comment: 100 users has been the growth rate for about 30 consecutive days. Sure, it's difficult to make an estimation, but the scenario is very likely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you need a fancy server configuration. From what I understand HTTPS is used to secure the link between the client and the server and basically ensures that you are connected to the server you think that you are. But any HTTPS capable client will be able to connect to the server and request your files. So it won't help with what you are trying to do. (If you were trying to prevent someone from impersonating your server then you would use it.)

To solve the problem you describe you'll probably want to use standard file encryption. This will keep your content safe from anyone that does not have the cryptographic key. Someone will eventually be able to dig the key out of your app, but you can update to new keys and hopefully make it more of a pain than it is worth.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Where would you store the cryptographic key inside the app? Could you recommend any library for that purpose? Would a password zip-file suffice?

Comment: Everything you need except for the key should be in Android. Look up javax.crypto under Android. The key should be stored in the app, probably as a string.

Comment: I'm not sure what support there is in Android for password protected zip files, but those are generally regarded as less secure. Both solutions are just base level "keeping honest people honest" type of protection.